# Does file directory/folder your code is in matter when using python3 modules ? I had an Issue

Tags: files, kali-linux, gui, python3

I am asking as lately while doing python GUI programing I installed tkinter by doing

```
apt-get install python3-tk
```

everything went well and when I opened python3 console while I was in the following directory

```
~/python-gui/
```

But I moved to an other folder called "tkinter" in "python-gui" folder and tried to compile the following code

```
 import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me)"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

        self.QUIT = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                                            command=root.destroy)
        self.QUIT.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

I did

```
python3 tkinter.py
```

and surprisingly I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "/root/python_gui/tkinter/tkinter.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Application(tk.Frame):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Frame'
```

so I entered python3 console from that path and tried importing tkinter inside the console but again got the same error, but when I try compiling the same code under "python-gui" folder directly it imports and compiles properly,
and also when I am in "~/python-gui/tkinter/" folder I tried

```
/usr/bin/python3.4
```

tkinter didnt import again but I come out and try again it does, why isn't python module not working in the "/tkinter/" folder ?
and how do I fix this ?

Thank you.

os info : Linux root 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.0.4-1+kali2 (2015-06-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux

python : python 3.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my bad, I named the program file tkinter.py while calling module tkinter, modules should usually work irrespective of the folder, just renaming the file name did the job. 
You can name your file name similar to a modules name, as there will be a file for it already.